# Why does Netbeans highlight some javascript methods as undefined

Tags: javascript, netbeans, methods

I have just started using Netbeans. And have imported a previously running project to get started. On loading the project Netbeans highlights a number of 'issues' most of which involve some methods within classes being identified as undefined.

So for instance:

```
var farmFile = farmFile || {};
farmFile.toolBarAUIHelp = new toolBarAUIHelp()|| {};

function toolBarAUIHelp(){

   this.helpMessageArray = [];
   this.errorMessageArray = [];

   this.helpMessageArray[ "geoLocationTitle" ] = {
      "insert":"String value here",
      "update":"String value here",
      "delete":"String value here"
      };


   this.errorMessageArray[ "geoLocation" ] = {
      "insert":"String value here",
      "update":"String value here",
      "delete":"String value here"
      };


   this.setToolBarAUIHelp = function ( var1, var2 ) {

      //set toolBar help message
      return;

     };

   this.setToolBarAUIError = function ( var1, var2) {
       //set toolBar error message
       return;
    };

}
```

Netbeans gives the errors:

setToolBarAUIHelp( var1, var2) undefined

setToolBarAUIError( var1, var2) undefined

Comment: empty `return;` at the end of function is very strange thing. mb NetBeans worry abouit that? :)

Comment: and you create arrays `this.helpMessageArray = [];` but use it like objects. I think there is an error. So next functions will never declare

Comment: Well, the methods will return `undefined`. It might be warning you about that. I wouldn't exactly trust NetBeans with JavaScript, though, so there is that.